# Tensorflow divergent loss in Boston Tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, linear-regression

I'm really got stucked in this particular example. So, I wonder if there anyone who has faced the same problem. [This](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/input_fn) is the tutorial page that I encountered the problem. When I execute; `regressor.train(input_fn=get_input_fn(training_set), steps=5000)` line, the loss is exponentially diverges. Therefore, the weights I receive at the end would not produce realistic predictions. Since whole example is in an **as is** status, I couldn't intervened with the process.

When I apply the Normal Equation with `Theta = pinv(X'*X) * X' * y`, the predictions I do with `Theta` are:

```
[33.624  17.714  21.796  33.601  12.852  19.621]
```

and the outcomes that proposed as true in the tutorial are:

```
[33.30348587  17.04452896  22.56370163  34.74345398  14.55953979   19.58005714]
```

Seemingly the **normal equation** produces nearly correct outputs. I designed my own model which consists of only one neuron and the loss was still diverging exactly as the tutorial model. Then I applied mean normalization and feature scaling which managed to converge the loss to a local minima. But when I multiplied the weights with the prediction set, then it produced negative results which are meaningless.

My question is, how can I fix that?

EDIT: Below is the code:

```
training_set = csvread('boston_train.csv');
training_set = training_set(2:end,:);
training_set = training_set(:,1:10);
```

First trim the first line since it contains meaningless data. And trim the last 2 columns which only contains 0's that don't stored in csv file. Probably a minor issue of `csvread` function.

```
y = training_set(:,10);
X = training_set(:,1:9);
```

Extracted outputs and features.

```
m = size(X,1);
X_norm = featureNormalize(X);
X = [ones(m,1) X_norm];
Theta = zeros(n,1); # Zero initialize the weight vector.
alpha= 0.01; # Learning rate.
```

Feature scaling and mean normalization is applied.

```
[Theta,losses]= gradientDescent(X, y, Theta, alpha, 5000);
fprintf('Final Loss computed = %f\n', losses(end));
```

Loss will be around 16.551243.

```
predict_set = csvread('boston_predict.csv');
predict_set = predict_set(:,1:9);
predict_set= predict_set(2:end,:);
ps_size = size(predict_set,1);
predict_set=[ones(ps_size,1) predict_set];
```

Some preprocessing of predict_set to get rid of redundant values.

```
predictions = predict_set * Theta
```

The resulting vector is:

```
  57.254
 -96.769
 -39.343
 -10.582
 -111.768
 -88.005
```